# Break up Calendar view multi-day task bar?

Tags: calendar, custom, sharepoint-calendar, application-pages

Is there a way to split the multi-day event bar at the top of the calendar so it is displayed as a single bar for each day (SharePoint 2013)?  For instance, an event that ran from Monday to Friday would be shown as 5 individual event bars on each day rather than one bar spanning the top of the calendar work week.

Note: I do not want to create a recurring event and I would like the proper start and end time to be reflected on the first and last days.